# how to view the number of task in the current queue?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

i get a index rejected exception when concurrent **index document** operation.

```
rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler@6d1cb827 
 on EsThreadPoolExecutor
 [
     index, 
     queue capacity = 200, 
     org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@5d6lae0c
     [
         Running, 
         pool size = 32, 
         active threads = 32, 
         queued tasks = 312, 
         completed tasks = 32541513
     ]
 ]
```

---

i try to visit the url, but the index queue field is aways **0**.

```
/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=id,type,name,size,largest,active,queue_size,queue
```

[image]

---

**question 1**: the queue capacity is 200, why is the munber of tasks in queue is 312 (over 200) ?

**question 2**: how to view the number of task in the current queue?